# UPDATE column in accessdb

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

Trying to update one column using the following method. No exception but the database is not updating.

```
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Saumil\Projects\NewProj\LoginInfo.accdb");
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from UserInfo", conn);

            DataSet dss = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(dss, "UserInfo");

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE UserInfo SET [Password] = @Password WHERE UserName = 'MyName'", conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtBoxPassword.Text);

            da.UpdateCommand = cmd;
            da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
```

Comment: OLE DB parameters are positional, not named. Although JET/ACE do some weird stuff with it you can sometimes get away with it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1